# linked in login using oauth2 causing page not found error

Tags: python, oauth, python-social-auth

I am using python social auth to use linked in for login.but page is not found in the following link

for the better convenience i am sharing my related files here.

my settings.py(linked in related portion)

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
#'django_social_project',
'social.apps.django_app.default',
)

LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_KEY = '*************'  # The LinkedIn application "API Key"
LINKEDIN_CONSUMER_SECRET = '**************' # The LinkedIn application "Secret Key"
SOCIAL_AUTH_LINKEDIN_SCOPE = ['r_basicprofile']

TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_PATH],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
            'django.core.context_processors.media',
            'django.core.context_processors.static',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'django.core.context_processors.tz',
            'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.backends',
            'social.apps.django_app.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ]
    },
},
]


AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (

'social.backends.linkedin.LinkedinOAuth2',
'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',

)


LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login/'
LOGIN_ERROR_URL = '/error/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

and in my template

```
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'linkedin-oauth2' %}">Login with LinkedIn</a>
```

after clicking in this link,i am redrecting in the following link
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?state=obuwGhdaVP8ypyN4pcPbgvftFbOwGy76&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fcomplete%2Flinkedin-oauth2%2F%3Fredirect_state%3DobuwGhdaVP8ypyN4pcPbgvftFbOwGy76&response_type=code&client_id=None

and  getting **page not found** on the web server.not sure whats going wrong.